# Submit multiple python jobs in parallel with different inputs from another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, subprocess, arguments

I have a python script where I need to provide flagged args, eg:

```
python test.py -i input_file -p parameter_1 -o output_file
```

I am making a pipeline using python (pipeline.py) where I want to run test.py parallelly with different inputs.

If I run a for loop as below, it runs sequentially, but I want to submit parallel jobs for atleast 5 inputs since I have more number of cores.

```
for inputs in input_file_list:
    subprocess.run(['python', 'test.py', "-i "+inputs, "-p 10", "-o "+inputs+"_output.csv"])
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `mpire` library.

Answer (score 1):

Just use asyncio

```
import asyncio
import os


def run_command(command: str = "") -> None:
    os.system(command)


async def run_command_async(command: str = "") -> None:
    await asyncio.to_thread(run_command, command)


async def main() -> None:
    input_file_list = []
    await asyncio.gather(
        *[run_command_async(f"python test.py -i {inputs} -p 10 -o {inputs}_output.csv") for inputs in input_file_list]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```